# ngx chart bubble chart- customizing data input

Tags: angular, bubble-chart, ngx-charts

i have used ngx-chart bubble chart for my project but when data comes in as the following format below and chart breaks:

```js
multi: any[] =[{
"name": "Kuwait",
"series": 
[{
"name": "a",
"waiting time": 24,
"real time": 38,
"queue size": 31
},
{
"name": "b",
"waiting time": 32,
"real time": 12,
"queue size": 20
}
}];
```

i have changed **'x','y' and 'r' property names to 'waiting time', 'real time ' and 'queue size'**.
It throws type errors.
How can i make bubble chart work with these data?

Comment: you need to convert your property to x, y and r property

Comment: how you can add space in json property ? "waiting time"

Comment: we are dealing with big data converting which will take lot of time and the property names will be dynamic.

Comment: there is my stackbitz example you can check it
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-object-property

Answer (score 0):

> I think you cant change axis names, 
>   you can use label name x as 'waiting time' using property 'xAxisLabel'

Please refer [then link](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/master/docs/charts/bubble-chart.md)

Comment: i want to change the property name not the label name.